# How to save PDF files using Scrapy?

Tags: python, pdf, scrapy

I am new to Python and have a problem using Scrapy. I need to download some PDF files from URLs (The URLs point to PDFs, but there is no `.pdf` in them.) and store them in a directory.

So far I have populated my items with title (as you can see I have passed the title as metadata of my previous request) and the body (which I get from the response body of my last request).

When it uses the `with open` function in my code, though, I always get an error back from the terminal like this:

```
exceptions.IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Here is my code:

```
def parse_objects:
   ....
   item = Item()
   item['title'] = titles.xpath('text()').extract()
   item['url'] = titles.xpath('a[@class="title"]/@href').extract()
   request = Request(item['url'][0], callback = self.parse_urls)
   request.meta['item'] = item
   yield request

def parse_urls(self,response):   
   item = response.meta['item']
   item['desc'] = response.body
   with open(item['title'][1], "w") as f:
        f.write(response.body)
```

I am using `item['title'][1]` because the title field is a list, and I need to save the PDF file using the second item which is the name. As far as I know, when I use `with open` and there is no such a file, Python creates a file automatically.

I'm using Python 3.4.

Can anyone help?

Comment: post the `url` that you are running your spider on it. then we can test your code. post your `with open` function also

Comment: I found the solution by my self. I was trying to save pdf files which included in their title the character "/" so inside the function "with open" this seemed as a directory. I changed the backslash with an underscore (_) and everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score -1):

First you have find the Xpath of the URL, that you need to download.

And save those links into one list.

Import the python module name called Urllib   `{ import urllib }`

Use the keyword urllib.urlretrieve to download the PDF files.

Ex.,

```
import urllib

url=[]

url.append(hxs.select('//a[@class="df"]/@href').extract())


for i in range(len(url)):

        urllib.urlretrieve(url[i],filename='%s'%i)
```